# Django sql/syncdb commands fail with PostgreSQL backend

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to migrate a MySQL-based Django project to PostgreSQL. Unfortunately, all sql/syncdb commands fail as soon as I switch the database backend in settings.py.

`python manage.py sql profile` w/ MySQL:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `profile_department` (
     `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     [...]
```

`python manage.py sql profile` w/ PostgreSQL (psycopg2):

```
DatabaseError: relation "profile_department" does not exist
LINE 1: ...nt"."homepage", "profile_department"."gd_id" FROM "profile_d...
                                                         ^
```

Why does Django behave differently with the two DB backends?

Comment: When looking in the database do you have any tables?

Comment: Please show `create table` statement which is execute for Postgres (it is **not** the one you posted).

Comment: Why are you querying from the DB when generating sql? Looks like you have a query that triggers on module load... tut tut...

Comment: No, the database remains empty – which is expected, as the `sql` command only prints the SQL statements. – There is no `CREATE TABLE` statement when the PostgreSQL statement is used – just this error message. – I am not querying from the DB, just trying to create the table in my new (empty) PostgreSQL database (if that succeeds, I'll clean out the DB and issue a `syncdb` command to load the data from the JSON fixture (created from the MySQL DB using `dumpdata`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas was right, there were indeed two queries buried somewhere in models.py that referred to the Department class:

```
ROOT_DEPARTMENT = Department.objects.get(pk=14)
FACULTIES = Department.objects.filter(parent=ROOT_DEPARTMENT)
```

Thanks!